# git remote has no output

Tags: git, git-remote

I recently got a new Apple silicon Mac, where previously I've used Linux/Ubuntu. I'm using zsh in the default terminal app. I noticed that using

```
git remote
git remote -v
```

have no output even though I'm in a git repository that has a remote. For example

```
git push
```

works and

```
cat .git/config
```

gives

```
...
[branch "master"]
        remote = <URL OF REMOTE>
        merge = refs/heads/master
...
```

When I use my Linux machines, I get the expected result which is:

```
$ git remote
origin
```

and

```
$ git remote -v
origin <URL OF REMOTE> (fetch)
origin <URL OF REMOTE> (push)
```

so I'm wondering why `git remote` isn't working.

Comment: Does `.git/config` have a remote section listed?

Comment: What does `git ls-remote` show? (Grasping at straws.)

Comment: does the `remote = xxx` line you mention contain *a remote name* (e.g : `origin`) or *a complete url* (e.g : `ssh://git@github.com/some/repo`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to suggest that on this repo on this machine you do *not* in fact have a remote. Here's an idea: try adding one! Say

```
git remote add origin <URL OF REMOTE>
```

and see if your life gets better.

Comment: That's inconsistent with the statement that `git push` works.

Comment: @KeithThompson : it is technically possible to have a complete url specified as the "remote" of a remote tracking branch. In that case, you can have working pull/push defaults, without a configured remote. (note: I confirmed it works by manually editing a .git/config file, I don't know yet how the OP could have reached that state, but some elements clearly indicate that the OP doesn't have a named remote configured in his repo)

Comment: @KeithThompson No it isn't. Look at the config the OP showed. This _branch_ has a remote so pushing it is possible. But it is a URL, not a remote name; and the _repo_ has no remote.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know that was possible. Still don't know why. 8-)}